# Is there a way to build a type of dynamic array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement

I am building a hockey stick suggestion "app" based on answers to a quiz. In my quiz, I ask 5 questions about features. If a user doesn't care about one of those features, then they can mark that question "I don't care".  The features need to match those coming from a Google Sheets API that has a list of all the hockey sticks the user can match.

To suggest the right stick, I am trying to build a complex If statement that checks a user-built object against properties in a JSON API (The API has 18 objects /sticks). The object has 5 properties and gets the values from answers in a form based on user input. I am wanting to check all values against the various objects stored in the objects found in the JSON API. Then when the properties match push that object to a different array. The trick is that a user can answer "I don't care" to any of the 5 questions that build the object. (I have tried leaving it blank if a user doesn't care but what I tried didn't work) So if a user cares about answering questions 1 2 3 and 5 but marks question 4 - "I don't care" I would need still the other 4 values to match of the object to match those in the API and then push any object that has all matching values.

I have tried various if statements including a very large one with all 5 questions. That seems to be the closest. However, if a user doesn't care about a feature that what makes this very hard.

So the user object that gets built with the answers from the quiz is :

```
var user = {
    level: '',
    grip: '',
    flex: '',
    pattern: '',
    kickPoint: ''
}
```

Then for each one of those properties, I have an If statement that checks to see what the user answered, and then change the property to the user answer.
 So for example flex :

```
if (flex == '75-77 (Light)') {
    user.flex = "Light"; 
} else if (flex == '85 - 87 (Standard)') {
    user.flex = "Regular";
} else if (flex == '95+ (Stiff)') {
    user.flex = "Stiff"; 
} else {
    user.flex = "I don't care"; 
}
```

Then once all properties have something, my if statement that has gotten close is (for properties like flex, in my google sheet I have it say Light, Regular or Stiff depending on what the stick is available in. Hence why there are includes ):

```
for (var j = 0; j < data.user.length; j++) {

    if ( user.level == data.user[j].level && 
         user.grip == data.user[j].grip && 
         data.user[j].pattern.includes(user.pattern) && 
         data.user[j].flex.includes(user.flex) && 
         user.kickPoint ==  data.user[j].kickpoint
      ) {

             userStick.push(data.user[j]); 

         }             

}
```

So far I get mixed results and I am not sure what else to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding of the problem, the stick should be included in the result even if the user selected "I don't Care" for some of the features. If that's the case, you can do:

```
for (var j = 0; j < data.user.length; j++) {

    if ((user.level === "I don't Care" || user.level === data.user[j].level) && 
         (user.grip === "I don't Care" || user.grip === data.user[j].grip) && 
         (user.pattern === "I don't Care" || data.user[j].pattern.includes(user.pattern)) && 
         (user.flex === "I don't Care" || data.user[j].flex.includes(user.flex)) && 
         (user.kickPoint === "I don't Care" || user.kickPoint === data.user[j].kickpoint)
      ) {

             userStick.push(data.user[j]); 
         }             
}
```

If you want user to select "I don't Care" for no more than one feature, you can check for that like so:

```
Object.values(user).filter(function (feature) { return feature === "I don't Care" }).length <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you are after, but if you want to filter those »I don't care« options a simple approach can be the use of a symbol/constant like that:

```
const I_DONT_CARE = Symbol(); // or = {}

//code

//example for flex
if (flex == '75-77 (Light)') { … }
else {
  user.flex = I_DONT_CARE;
}

//more code

for (var j = 0; j < data.user.length; j++) {
  if (
   //flex
   (user.flex !== I_DONT_CARE && user.flex == data.user[j].flex) &&
   //more other properties
  ) {
    // it is not »I don't care«
  }
}
```

If you just need to test if any of the options of the object is `I_DONT_CARE`, you can use such a test:

```
const hasIDontCare = Object.entries(data).some(i => i === I_DONT_CARE);
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

I have just tried to outline the idea of using a constant. This way you can use the `===` operator to check for that specific answer, if that is what you are after.